# Is there a way to create an half pie chart filled with dots in ECharts?

Tags: echarts

I would like to create a chart like this in ECharts:

[image: Example Chart]

Is there a way?

I tried using an example from the ECharts page, but after trying to cut the chart in half, some dots were missing and the `endAngle` was not correct.

Answer (score 2):

I dont think there is some out of the box graph type you can use. Depending on your usecase a pie chart or sunburst might be a suitable alternative.

You are probably talking about [this example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=pie-parliament-transition) chart which you tried to adjust. If you want the exact chart on the image adjusting the example is the way to go. [Here](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=pie-parliament-transition&code=MYewdgzgLgBAJgQygmBeGBtAUDGBvGANwQBsBXAUwC4YAOABnoBoYwEBbamAcgEFuYAXyY58RUpRoA2AMwBWFm041uAIQHDRBYuS5yGijl24BhDSNzaJXACy0bh5TwAi5reN00ZjR8YCibpYekjAATD6sRioAYhpYALoA3FigkLBwFABmCGQkUAAKpBRQUBRomKIA9JU8AMRyAIxStACcAEbcLNy1wBRywP2ddZltwPIA7EPdtCOZM1O1UnItcPYLI7QUUggLwOPjobS0C-O0UvQt9AstDcA2AwvNl207ot1yNuP0wFKdb7U3YB7OR_XDdbLAWj6UF1ChbKQImHdcYyYD0DJI2oyF6hA6YzKQmxyUKYloIc5tGyYigIcZA4DcBLJVLQGAAJwQcAAlmQIOUMNxvABSKYMEVJFLgVkABwQbJIXKMYCgAHlpVAueBygAKTJkMDADVa7UASnwohIxRgEDI7HKiGQADo2RQ4GRerr9YbNWAYNqbewWMAyGyzXhRLgXVAQ76AzAANQwYNsx06SjJXDCGD0E0ZmCW2AIMAAc0tfPQGAluAL1uQbKgvBLlvKAFkkAALR35ACSeZrycbpbK6GgcobTYoeYdCEdmRAbL8CGA7c9BqNvu1XNK7DDEZgRaHEEd0t5K4HE9ze_PQ4T6E329T1hgNQDZoAVDA21BOz284JL7gB5lsep7-nW443omX4_t2AEwHqa4-jAsryoqnDKgAMggACeIBkFAYFjoOlosBQYBwMRFAsFAIDICQlEsGyzDsg0LAQFyABeFC7rg1ZWmyIAAO4QCYeHKq2HaOr0XIkNq2psg0MAALTsjmz7Wpx3F5nxsDSiAXLKuWmBVrxNZsuUTHafB85-jWXLlPQiQwPZAA87JCSJYlQE5XLxvGPG8bg1QwAAShQwCkMGJBIGU7FcXuOkwDRdEhQZxYAMo0lAEAAHK2m0FDmeg0HOmJcByclpCUTAH6hupcVaQl-ZWmAFCCelmk6pV9ETjV7JmjU3WpSWmVILl-WFVZuBzuZ2pNYlADWEnfrOJAgPOcmjvW1W1QNrBtR1XHvvt7WaVNvFLW5JWZGtG3amRFG9bt6mtadR19a9h1lCpDQUEpUjnbgS3xugn2aU1AWBYlQHDjAS01GygPNbAAAey2dqAEDajDx2I_NyMwNh6OOuxYDYxefV41DvF6QZ2UgRAK4YCjLDYfEcGBYITXmSDGlcVZXOBVGMbIfphl_qIwtsr64aBRAhVchQEA0LLUNQNh0rGMG0AgOwMKBVycAqNy0BslybT4T6-u8dONDThYUOgPO3JsKU6XYdAFDsDQ-oZJkBmug7gX6lyhCFRApAACocpAW4-jQUBspQQe8UWXLsEgPrOCGmfgAAqtKDpcA0jDMNzD2Fd2240Ah3rGihHAQCwCDSlykNQ8Q5mG2j6AN-wR7Tt25EUCjSOd0QitvbDJXsAZ2Ot46xbFAA6ob36ms3C9L1AAASFBcsW7YESaHMd3Kqk6tqKHy9Ea1IPJnI8hAGD0Oz6kl2pH6EJPX17aEY_nwUpfa-FBb4gHvhybkvIMANDfjUD-x1v4HU0n_AB5lgA933FvFea8VzHXoI6OQaCkxE3QC3Lki9ih7wPkfU0fUCFEPxuPBq5QkFT3UnIRyTDz600MuUFCColRQCwrhfCc1qaBRhs_bu8QU7UykRgbuCYYCwLkVDEqPY-qhDUULMuEjeIKR0bxFhiYZD41PkLYoItVb6PVprFQxYBJkGlNbamy4ZJwBdGAGgvD6YZ2lKuOuG51Tt30VLGW-NqZ2K1lyNkwBLSuP0fufCIBVBIGXAnJOVFIlQ0Zi3LgNikmBQwTQDByj1Qv1kTktx2FSlE0TBU1R1SoZshoCwmooRmmZiMdTaA2FLQqy6bxf2JASB2yyDkPIhQCylEUXANGQp4ATNyAUIoJQKCOktCWb88QhmCyKUIJGmYTT40EOdfZmZRBnKwP-U0yQsAgHVEhXucpBHoVVE88AiQgA) is a quick adjustment that looks already quite close to your image.

---

**Edit**

Updated the the example a little further [here](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=pie-parliament-transition&code=MYewdgzgLgBAJgQygmBeGBtAUDGBvGANwQBsBXAUwC4YAWABgBoYwEBbamAcgEEuYAvoxz4ipSjQDMTFu05cAQvyEiCxcpwCMM1hxpcAwsuG414zgA5mu-QBFjqsRpoB2a3P0BRB6acSYku563ABiPqLq_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_QKtQHg3s7NACySAAFm0vmKc9L02d9b0BdAXw6N8Pwoc8p3aF4QA6TwEGAX9O27Xt-yWfo0wBNgN1wXBr3AiA2nLTMMNA2D7mItcOjAz9Vg7fCKDYQ8NBgcFhimAAqGAfygf9APPAQ6KvWDyMoiAMKgmDwLWQS_wA4oJIXbCB0rataw4esABkEAATxAMgoCGZBoKYihmAoMA4Gs5goBAZASEcmAOhkDo0mWNMAC8KCI4jLw6EAAHcIAMUz62_FS-jTEhBm8mAAFoPIObjfICiSnz-CsQDTet7wwR9gryjpmk889cCQir-kvNNmnoSoYEagAeDzwsi6KoBatNVlWIL6LBGAACUKGAUgxhIJBAQgfyKE3MrYGc1zRsKq4myQCAADlGgRZtYuEzporgQZVtIayYAEyZMvm7LquWlgKDChsFuafoLrc2Dro8qZwS-9aby2qBdv25tHpq5DByW-jLwAayO_8XkuZDBnkq6bv-57XoW_icbegKlM5TlIeIxGOqE5HUY6QY7Icn6scysAXsJwLfpZ3GibSzQKBSmEydwRGWIJhbYZgIb6IvPLSM_dBEfBDpBel2AAA8kbaUAIH6WX2Zu5XLyMjX5rAHXaN-pXxdwcsCqKiiqP6DBVeYIzyhy4iBHFiqRfuuCls9-jtw6JYbcK0GxJEIOlhHeioCM8t5DGaAQDYW1cDTOB9HTaAWwRMycLTlpkBoBDzVwUBkPTVgAQbIzoHYmhu2dF5Cu6MuYG7NNCGbCBSAAFRTSB8JwmgoA6Sh2-vNM2CQHDbHGWfwAAVXLKctHoDf266ezm2KAiaA0pdcO09gIGYBByzTSXcGICqM_V9AT7YciEOKHfVbJ2-iFbLmIOU462CFR1pfNoVw_gAHUM7CSHOfEBYCoAZAoGmK4v5zITHdjfKs6UPr9G0hACgIRLhIH6CmdMmYMD0DdplbQGUBKEB_mzbGmg2gC3Fl_ZKHZcFVnwYQkAxDSEZggBgTQVDwQ0PxvQ1meNqEsM_lg4AD8rxwIgVAjC-N6BtFyHIiqwAjboAvmmUBfxEHINQUOX6GiXDaKyn_SRv9MrcmsaHIqzRtI1jrFAQyJkzL9CtpJMiGB77lHbvRXWQj75KRESE4iVNVLRK3EwPx3l4k2KUpIcWGCPJ_B3DHKWuA44J30FcUKZByyF3ouhBKcBt40GcaDNoM9yyYUXDhQc5YoDXyllHfAfjY7x0TmmDowAzjlLyVeMyIAFBIHQqPceNlenEVkhfTguSxlSwUTQBRSl2kUOCQsipRlNlG3WDsqJ-ziIdBoL7Bx5yVBrPotAIyZwaCrPuTVBKJAS6vHeJ8H4Y4ASBLgOrXMzw3gfG-L8f45wzg3mEuUW5CyBDK3EuLJF_sRBovEkOaoWAQDtNaegXJfYoDPJ6Q8384VZkTxgEtAEqsoBXMaMwJaCIXLOTYPobk-ZmVw1eAy7g_puW0ooPShscdSV4CQvWNmNBCx3MEOafBLY2y1KrO4vSjZmytjPlgJFQA):

Code:

```js
// import * as echarts from 'echarts'; // in current example used CDN instead of this

/**
 ** Declare Chart
 */
const chartDom = document.getElementById('chart');
const myChart = echarts.init(chartDom);

/**
 ** Declare Example Dataset
 */
const data = [
  { value: 40, name: 'A' },
  { value: 30, name: 'B' },
  { value: 10, name: 'C' },
  { value: 8, name: 'D' },
  { value: 7, name: 'E' },
  { value: 3, name: 'F' },
  { value: 18, name: 'G' },
  { value: 31, name: 'H' },
  { value: 59, name: 'I' }
];

/**
 ** Calculate SUM number (to middle of text)
 */
const sum = data.reduce((sum, cur) => {
  return sum + cur.value;
}, 0);
console.log(sum);

/**
 ** Declare Color Template
 */
const defaultPalette = [
  // '#51689b', '#ce5c5c', '#fbc357', '#8fbf8f', '#659d84', '#fb8e6a', '#c77288', '#786090', '#91c4c5', '#6890ba'
  '#5470c6',
  '#91cc75',
  '#fac858',
  '#ee6666',
  '#73c0de',
  '#3ba272',
  '#fc8452',
  '#9a60b4',
  '#ea7ccc'
];

/**
 ** Declare Radius of Chart
 */
const radius = ['30%', '80%'];

/**
 ** Declare Series
 */
const parliamentSeries = (function () {
  let sum = data.reduce(function (sum, cur) {
    return sum + cur.value;
  }, 0);
  let angles = [];
  let startAngle = Math.PI;
  let curAngle = startAngle;
  data.forEach(function (item) {
    angles.push(curAngle);
    curAngle += (item.value / sum) * Math.PI;
  });
  angles.push(startAngle + Math.PI);
  function parliamentLayout(startAngle, endAngle, totalAngle, r0, r1, size) {
    let rowsCount = Math.ceil((r1 - r0) / size);
    let points = [];
    let r = r0;
    for (let i = 0; i < rowsCount; i++) {
      // Recalculate size
      let totalRingSeatsNumber = Math.round((totalAngle * r) / size);
      let newSize = (totalAngle * r) / totalRingSeatsNumber;
      for (
        let k = Math.floor((startAngle * r) / newSize) * newSize + 22;
        k < Math.floor((endAngle * r) / newSize) * newSize - 1e-6;
        k += newSize
      ) {
        let angle = k / r;
        let x = Math.cos(angle) * r;
        let y = Math.sin(angle) * r;
        points.push([x, y]);
      }
      r += size;
    }
    return points;
  }
  return {
    type: 'custom',
    id: 'distribution',
    data: data,
    coordinateSystem: undefined,
    universalTransition: true,
    animationDurationUpdate: 1000,
    renderItem: function (params, api) {
      var idx = params.dataIndex;
      var viewSize = Math.min(api.getWidth(), api.getHeight());
      var r0 = ((parseFloat(radius[0]) / 100) * viewSize) / 1.6;
      var r1 = ((parseFloat(radius[1]) / 100) * viewSize) / 1.6;
      var cx = api.getWidth() * 0.5;
      var cy = api.getHeight() * 0.7;
      var size = viewSize / 28;
      var points = parliamentLayout(
        angles[idx],
        angles[idx + 1],
        Math.PI,
        r0,
        r1,
        size + 3
      );
      return {
        type: 'group',
        children: points.map(function (pt) {
          return {
            type: 'circle',
            autoBatch: true,
            shape: {
              cx: cx + pt[0],
              cy: cy + pt[1],
              r: size / 2
            },
            style: {
              fill: defaultPalette[idx % defaultPalette.length]
            }
          };
        })
      };
    }
  };
})();

/**
 ** Declare Chart Option
 */
const option = {
  // Settings of text of middle
  title: {
    show: true,
    text: sum, // <-- here can give value to text of middle
    bottom: '28%',
    left: '42%',
    textStyle: { fontSize: 50 }
  },
  // Dateset/Series
  series: parliamentSeries
};

/**
 ** Generate Chart by Option
 */
myChart.setOption(option);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/5.4.2/echarts.min.js" integrity="sha512-VdqgeoWrVJcsDXFlQEKqE5MyhaIgB9yXUVaiUa8DR2J4Lr1uWcFm+ZH/YnzV5WqgKf4GPyHQ64vVLgzqGIchyw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<div id="chart" style="width: 600px; height: 600px;"></div>
```